# use-package & quelpa: resolve dependencies with elpa?

Tags: package, use-package, dependency

When modifying some packages I'm using `(use-package :load-path "my-forked-project")` but to make my config work in any machine I want get that package from say my github repo.

I'm now trying `quelpa` alongside `quelpa-use-package` but I'm having the following problem:
the dependencies of the package I'm loading from my github repo are also handled my `quelpa`, and thus instead of downloading the requirements of that package from elpa, their git repositories are cloned (and also I'm in a situation where this broke my config cause apparently the upstream repo has a problem..?).

Is there a way to have the dependencies of the package I'm getting from my git repo to be fetched with the normal `use-package` instead of `quelpa`?
I guess I can fix this by installing first myself the dependencies with `use-package`, but is there another way to handle this?